# Check Date Equals 1st Date of Month C#

Tags: c#

User can input any date, month and year like 12/12/2013, 1/1/2014, 7/5/2014, 5/1/2012 in MM\DD\YYYY format.

How to check the date is first date of month ?

If the user entry is not first date of month, I want to modify that entry to 1st date of month. In my Examples, I want

12/12/2013 as 12/1/2013
1/1/2014 as 1/1/2014(No Change)
7/5/2014 as 7/1/2014
5/1/2012 as 5/1/2012(No Change)

Thanks

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Anything wrong with `if (date.Day == 1)`?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Without any effort or code shown, it sounds like you're asking us to do it for you.

Comment: how about just letting the user pick the month and year?  That way you don't confuse them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime date = ... // your original date here...

// Don't bother checking, just create a new date for the 1st.
date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
```

UPDATE:
The OP has apparently changed the specs:

```
DateTime date = ... // your original date here...
if (date.Day != 1)
  date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
```

(let the .AddMonths() method worry about the year rolling over in December...)

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, OP doesn't necessarily always want the 1st of the current month but rather the 1st of the month of whatever date is given.

Comment: You can also create a specific moment in time with the DateTime constructor: `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1, etc.)`

Comment: @tnw -- I think you missed the "// or however you get it".  The origin of the date is irrelevant.  Using Now was easier for the sample than writing an input.

Comment: @JamesCurran Ah, I see that was edited in after I commented. Carry on.

Comment: tnw -- well, it seems that @cjcurrie also misunderstood it, so I figured it was time for some clarification.

Comment: @JamesCurran If the start date is not the first date of the month, I want the next month 1st date, not the current month first date.

Comment: @user3757426 - that is NOT what you said in the question...

Answer (score 0):

IMO, since you have a definite format you expect from users (MM\DD\YYYY) why not do a simple split and dig your hit:

```
string arbitDate = "4/3/2014";
string UsersFirstDay = arbitDate.Trim().Split(new String[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim();//index 1 is the DD part - according to your format
UsersFirstDay = (UsersFirstDay == "1") ? UsersFirstDay : "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your date to this function:

```
public static void ConvertToFirstDate(ref DateTime dt){
    TimeSpan ts = dt.Subtract(new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1));
    dt =  dt.AddDays(-ts.Days);
}
```

Comment: i still feel using ref and not returning a datetime does not helps much. i thought it will keep all other property and fields of dt intact if i do this. Expert comments plz!